# Using the Schema Generation Wizard to regenerate a previously-generated schema

Tags: sql-server, data-warehouse, ssas, visual-studio

Lately, I've been trying to clean up a group of projects that my company received from an outside contractor.  Among them is an SSAS cube, with an associated data warehouse.

The contractors generated the cube top-down, using the Schema Generation Wizard to generate the schema for the data warehouse from the cube.  Normally, based on what I've read about the SSAS tools in Visual Studio, you make changes to the data warehouse by changing the cube, and then re-running the Schema Generation Wizard to update the data warehouse.  I'd like to maintain the database using the SSAS tools so that we have one centralized place to manage both the cube and data warehouse's schema.

My goal with cleaning up these projects is to get them to run on developers' local machines.  That will require standing up a full new set of independent databases on each developer's machine.  I want to manage the data warehouse schema from the SSAS tools, so I'd like to fully regenerate the schema each time we stand up a new developer.

I'm not concerned with data or stored procedures in the data warehouse at the moment.  I'd be fine with completely deleting the data warehouse and regenerating it when needed.  Deleting the `.dsv` file will not be an option, however, because it contains queries against the table structure defined by the cube.

Is there any way to regenerate a previously-generated schema using the Schema Generation Wizard, without deleting the `.dsv`?

Comment: How is this question different than https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/204087/79569? My answer there still is how I would answer here.

Comment: I didn't get a satisfactory answer, so I changed that question and added a bounty.  A moderator, Paul White, rolled back the question and the bounty and told me to ask a refined version of it.  I'm really looking for the "how", moreso than whether this is a good approach or not.

Comment: @TomV I explained how I would recommend doing it on the other thread. Apparently julian-goldsmith wants to do it another way.

Comment: @greggalloway: I was looking for how to use the Schema Generation Wizard to do this.  I have other ways I can do it, but I'm trying to manage the cube entirely from one place.

Comment: @julian-goldsmith understood. I wouldn't do it that way since you have already generated the schema previously.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't delete the .dsv in a *copy* of your Visual Studio project, and re-run the Schema Generation Wizard?  This worked for me on a test using VS2017.  Or have you tried this and receive an error?

Comment: @wBob: I could possibly do something like that and restore it using Git.  I wouldn't consider that straightforward as far as setup instructions go, though.

Comment: I would do that as a one-off.  Take a copy of the project locally then create the db schema.  Next import it into a Visual Studio Database Project.  Include that in the same solution as the cube if you like.  Now maintain the database schema using the database project and the cube via the multi-dimensional project.  I think you *might* be creating an artificial barrier for yourself by saying you only want to use the "Schema Generation Wizard" tooling because, as you've pointed out, doing it over and over again is not that straightforward.  Make sense?

Comment: Not really.  Logically, I'd be able to simply run the Schema Generation Wizard on an empty database, and it would generate a fresh schema for me.  What actually happens is that it complains about dimensions being bound to user tables.  I have other ways to manage the DB schema.  Since the database is based on the cube, though, rather than the other way around, I'd prefer to make my changes in the cube, and have Visual Studio update the data warehouse for me.